# React-router error accessing directly by the path or refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have implemented react-router without any problem, it's working properly, but for some reason in the case an user refresh the page or try to access directly to a different page of the main one by the path i'm getting an error like Cannot GET /whatever (e.g. Cannot GET /blog).

Below is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'store';

// Layouts
import App from 'layouts/app';

// Components
import Portfolio     from 'ui/portfolio';
import BlogContainer from 'ui/blog-container';
import TimeLine      from 'ui/timeline';
import About         from 'ui/about'
import Contact       from 'ui/contact'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

        <Route component={App}>
            <Route path="/" component={Portfolio} />
            <Route path="/blog" component={BlogContainer} />
            <Route path="/timeline" component={TimeLine} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Route>

    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any idea how can I fix it.

```
Note: dependencies I am using
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1"
```

Comment: Can you show us the lines before `ReactDOM.render` ?

Comment: add an <IndexRoute component={Portfolio} />, also remove '/' from routes except for root path.

Comment: Could you replace `browserHistory` by `hashHistory` and try `#/your-route` urls, just for test purposes

Comment: @KeitIG I made the change you said and it's working, but now the path looks like http://localhost:8000/#/blog?_k=h779se and not like http://localhost:8000/blog is there any way to keep the path clean?

Comment: Yep, that was just a test to know what were the problem, I'll try to post an answer soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your server router (nginx, Apache...) does not know what to return and what content to deliver to your browser. Basically, if your app is only a front end app that you have already bundled, admitting you're using nginx, you need this kind of config for your server:

```
server {

    location / {
        try_files $uri /your/index.html; # the path to your html page
    }
}
```

Then, when you will try to go directly to a route, your server will always return the html page containing your javascript bundle, and `react-router` should handle the rest.

See the [this explanation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing) in the docs of `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

Remove '/' from your routes. Directly call component. 
Eg: 
{

```
<Route component={ App } path='/master'>
        <Route path = 'board' component={BoardView} />
        <Route  path = 'team'  component={View} />
        <Route path = 'all' component={All} />
        <Route path = 'shots' component={Shots} />
        <Route path = 'home' component={Home} />
        <Route path = 'topper' component={Toppers} />
        <Route path = 'overlay' component={Overlay} />
        <Route path = 'earn' component={Earn} />
```

}

Comment: I made your change an doesn't work. Location "/blog" did not match any routes and I use the { Link } from 'react-router' to generate the links.